# AWS Java SDK is taking old version of jackson jar

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, jackson, build.gradle

Currently I am working to add AWS Java SDK in my existing application to perform operations related to  AWS cloud. While importing the aws java sdk for latest version i.e.1.11.113 I am getting run time exception. After researching about exception the reason is java sdk using deprecated version or incompatible version for jackson jar.

The sdk is using jackson jar of version 4.1 while required version must at least 5. Even I am giving latest jackson jar but still it is taking reference of jar present in SDK. Below code snapshot will help to identify this easily

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.enable([Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser$Feature;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
    at com.amazonaws.partitions.PartitionsLoader.<clinit>(PartitionsLoader.java:54) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.113.jar:]
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionMetadataFactory.create(RegionMetadataFactory.java:30) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.113.jar:]
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.initialize(RegionUtils.java:64) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.113.jar:]
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegionMetadata(RegionUtils.java:52) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.113.jar:]
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegion(RegionUtils.java:105) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.113.jar:]
    at com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Region.java:43) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.113.jar:]
```

How can I avoid code to use this particular jar and make it use latest jar . I am using gradle as build tool.

Comment: which jackson lib are you talking about ? the [FasterXML/jackson lib](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Releases) is currently in 2.8 (prod / 2.9 in dev) version and aws sdk includes version 2.6.6.

Comment: I am using AWS JAVA SDK 1.11.113 which is internally hitting jackson jar 4.1. This is cause of exception.

Comment: well the 1.11.113 pom.xml declares jackson 2.6.6 version : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/2bf561f0a27e5b4b51c5fa730baf4c6af7c36fc3/pom.xml#L142

Comment: but com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() is giving 2.4 that means internally it is still using older version

Answer (score 3):

Are you using maven? I had a similar issue to use joda-time before and then solved using by `<exclusion>` tag. `<exclusion>` tag could be used to exclude the old jackson in your aws-java-sdk. Following is the way to solve the issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.113</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is the right idea but it is not fixing the problem for me. If you have other thoughts pls post.. Note that I also added exclusion for `jackson-databind` but also did not resolve.