# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with AWS SDK

Tags: java, maven, aws-sdk

I'm attempting to upload images to Amazon S3 bucket using the following code:

```
   AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()

   .withRegion("us-east-1")
   .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
   .build();
```

However, Eclipse throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:537)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:448)
    at com.amazonaws.partitions.PartitionsLoader.<clinit>(PartitionsLoader.java:51)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionMetadataFactory.create(RegionMetadataFactory.java:30)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.initialize(RegionUtils.java:64)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegionMetadata(RegionUtils.java:52)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils.getRegion(RegionUtils.java:105)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.getRegionObject(AwsClientBuilder.java:249)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.withRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:238)
    at order_fulfilment.amazon.AmazonS3API.perform(AmazonS3API.java:68)
    at amzn.Main.main(Main.java:126)
```

Based on [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1459) thread it seems to be an issue with Jackson version. However, I tried every version of Jackson (including version 2.6.7 and 2.6.6. as suggested in thread) to no avail.

I was able to confirm the Jackson version was correct using the following code:

```
System.out.println(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

As suggested in [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1167) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362138/aws-java-sdk-is-taking-old-version-of-jackson-jar) thread on stackoverflow.

What am I doing wrong?

**All Dependencies:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>amz</groupId>
    <artifactId>amz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>lib</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
            <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>





        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
            <version>v4-rev520-1.23.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.gshell.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>gshell-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.358</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Note:** I played around with many different versions of each dependency (this is the most recent version I tried) but they all lead to the same error.

Comment: @SeanBright Maven

Comment: I tried removing all Jackson dependencies from POM file however this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: I removed everything except for 'aws-java-sdk-s3' but it still does not work.

Comment: It should work if you use only s3 sdk

Comment: Whats the error when you use only s3 sdk?

Comment: @SeanBright updated with all dependencies

Comment: @PankajSinghal the exact same error

Comment: @S.O.S your transitive dependencies are in conflict. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to see where the older versions of Jackson are being included.

Comment: @SeanBright OK I will check. Thanks for spending so much time on this question!

Comment: You definitely have a conflict with jackson - AWS is trying to call a method that doesn't exist in the version it's resolving to. Since you say you've tried several different versions, is it possible you have those classes in your classpath multiple times (possibly from different jars)? This can cause all sorts of classloading pain (like ClassA being loaded from one jar, but ClassB loaded from the other - loads of fun)